Using usePathname in production isn't working
This code successfully changes font to bold on the corresponding nav link according to the currentPath in development but does not work in production.
I am using "use client" and I have all the correct imports and interfaces.
function HorizontalList({ links }: HorizontalListProps) {
  const currentPath = usePathname();

  return (
    <List>
      <HStack as="ul" spacing={6} listStyleType="none" m={0} p={0}>
        {links.map((link, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index}>
            <Link
              href={link.href}
              _hover={{}}
              color="belleBlue"
              className={classnames({
                "font-bold": currentPath === link.href,
                "hover:opacity-70 transition-all": true,
              })}
            >
              {link.label}
            </Link>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </HStack>
    </List>
  );
}


This line of code fixed my issue, specifically {ssr: false}
 const isDesktop = useBreakpointValue({ base: false, md: true }, {ssr: false});


It's great that you figured out a solution by yourself and decided to share it! Your answer could be improved by explaining what the cause of your issue was and how the snippet relates to your original question. From the looks of things the useBreakpointValue hook is an implementation detail of one of the components (probably <HStack>?) which is not clear from this answer.
